# Enumeration Principle and countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure I understand the "Enumeration Principle" which says that every set that can be labeled by a countable set is countable. For instance my book proves that the set of all rationals is countable by showing it can be labeled by the set $L = ${$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -, /$}. But then I thought: couldn't we use this idea to get nonsense results, like proving that $[0, 1]$ is countable because it can be labeled by the set {$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, .$}? Also, what is the relationship between this idea and the idea of defining a bijection between sets? I guess, more crudely, I'm asking what is the mathematical import of this "listable" idea?

Comment: How do you propose to labelling all the numbers in $[0,1]$ with the set $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$? It does turn out that this is not possible. See [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument).

Comment: @MikePierce I must be misunderstanding the idea of "labelling." I understand Cantor's diagonal argument, but I thought this idea of labelling is just saying that any number in the set can be written with the symbols of $L$. So any number in $[0, 1]$ will be composed of the symbols in my proposed list...

Comment: @WilsonBrians In a labelling, you label each element with **one** label. So you'd need to assign a *single* number from $\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ to (say) $\pi$. When you say "any number in $[0, 1]$ will be composed of the symbols", you're talking about assigning to each number in $[0, 1]$ an *infinite sequence* of these symbols.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh I see. But aren't there rational numbers that would require an infinite sequence of the symbols in $L$? For instance $\frac{1}{999...}$. I.e., where $9$'s repeat infinitely.

Comment: @WilsonBrians First of all, the "number" you describe isn't a rational number: the denominator isn't an integer (you can't have an infinitely long integer). The broader point, though, is that *you have to be clever*. Labellings of $\mathbb{Q}$ are somewhat tricky; as a first step, you might think about how you'd label *ordered pairs* of integers (HINT: [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)...)

Comment: Labeling assumes *finite* labels.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually, in this context I think "labelling" means labelling with a *single* symbol. (Of course it ultimately doesn't make a difference, since there are exactly as many finite strings of symbols from an infinite set $I$ as there are elements of $I$, but still.)

Comment: No, I think he's talking about labeling with words in the alphabet $\{0,\cdots,9,/\}$. These can't be used to label the real numbers because infinite sequences of these symbols aren't words. @NoahSchweber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtle point is that the labels are *finite*. And the set of finite sequences of characters from a countable alphabet is countable. And we can prove that if $X$ is a countable set, and $f$ is a function defined on $X$, then the range of $f$ is also countable.

Sure, you could label every number in $[0,1]$ by a string of digits, say $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9\}$. But almost always, this string will have to be infinite.

Here we see the importance of not hiding under "handwavy intuitive explanations", and relying on precise definitions of what it means to be labeled, countable, and so on.